# Insert a value after another value in a list

Tags: python, list

I would like a function called `insert_after` which will take a list and two values (`search_value` and `value`).

The functionality should then be to insert `value` after the first occurrence of `search_value`

If `search_value` is *not* in the list, then add it to the end. I would like to use a `try...except` statement to do this.

For example, if the list is:

```
myList = [4,2,6,7,8,1],
```

then the function call:

```
insert_after(myList, 7, 5)
```

should return:

```
[4,2,6,7,5,8,1]
```

---

I've attempted it, but my value keeps getting inserted at the end of the list even though I specify the index.

```
def insert_after(list1, search_value, value):
    try:
        for i in list1:
            if i == search_value:
                list1.insert(search_value+1,value)
            else:
                list1.insert(len(list1)+1,value)
    except:
        list1.insert(len(list1)+1,value)
```

Comment: `search_value` is value, not index

Comment: Hey verdy, it looks like you have never accepted an answer to your questions. Please consider marking the best answer by clicking the green checkmark next to it. This will point out that the problem was resolved to future readers and will also give you a slight reputation boost.

Answer (score 5):

You need to first find the index of `search_value` in the list, which can be done with the `.index` method. Then, you can use the `.insert` method to insert the `value` at the position after that (the index `+1`).

However, we need to consider the case where `search_value` is *not* in `lst`. For this, we simply use a `try...except` to catach the `ValueError` for when the `.index` fails. And, in this case, we want to either append to `lst`, or `.insert` at the end; either works.

```
def insert_after(lst, search_value, value):
    try:
        lst.insert(lst.index(search_value)+1, value)
    except ValueError:
        lst.append(search_value)
        #or: lst.insert(len(lst)-1, value)
```

and a test:

```
>>> l = [4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 1]
>>> insert_after(l, 7, 5)
>>> l
[4, 2, 6, 7, 5, 8, 1]
```

---

*why didn't your method work?*

If we look closely at your main insertion line:

```
list1.insert(search_value+1,value)
```

we can see that your logic is slightly off. The `.insert` method takes an index and a value. Here, you are passing `search_value+1` as the *index* even though this is really just the value.

So hopefully you can see from my code, that using the `.index` method is the right way to go since it gives us the *index of that value* - allowing us to use `.insert` correctly.

*what if you don't want to use `.index`?*

So, yes, you *could* use a `for-loop`, but instead of iterating over the terms as you are, you really want to be iterating over the values *and the indexes*. This can be achieved using `enumerate()`.

So, I will let you put this in a function by yourself since it is likely you will just end up using the `.index` method, but the basic idea would be something along the lines of:

```
for i, e in enumerate(lst):
    if e == search_value:
        lst.insert(i+1, value)
```

Comment: I was about to comment that +1 was missing.

Comment: @Rahul Yeah I only noticed when writing the explanation :p

Answer (score 1):

syntax of insert => list1.insert(index,element);

but here you specify search_value.and also you can use index function to get the index of a value in list.

the function look like this.

```
def insert_after(list1, search_value, value):
try:
    index = list1.index(search_value);
    list1.insert(index+1,value);
except:
    list1.insert(len(list1)+1,value)
```

when the value not present in the list it will raise ValueError.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_index(mylist, search_value):
    """return index number; returns -1 if item not found"""
    try:
        return mylist.index(search_value)
    except ValueError as ve:
        # ValueError would be thrown if item not in list
        return -1  # returns -1 if item not in list

def insert_after(list1, search_value, value):
    index = get_index(list1, search_value)
    if index != -1:
        """inserts after index"""
        list1.insert(index + 1, value)
    else:
        """appends to the end of list"""
        list1.append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you'll need to get the index value for the point you want to insert your value.

```
def insert_after(myList, i, j):
    try:
        myList.insert(myList.index(i)+1, j)
    except ValueError:
        myList.append(j)
```

You can read a bit more on lists here; https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way is to find the index of insertion with a generator. This allows to give a default value to hide the exception handling of `list.index`.

Here is a solution that *creates* a new list.

```
def insert_after(list1, search_value, value):
    i = next((i + 1 for i in range(len(list1)) if list1[i] == search_value), len(list1))
    return [*list1[:i], value, *list1[i:]]

insert_after([1, 2, 3], 2, 'foo') # [1, 2, 'foo', 3]
insert_after([1, 2, 3], 10, 'bar') # [1, 2, 3, 'bar']
```

And here is a solution that *mutates* your existing list.

```
def insert_after(list1, search_value, value):
    i = next((i + 1 for i in range(len(list1)) if list1[i] == search_value), len(list1))
    list1.insert(i, value)

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
insert_after(list1, 2, 'foo')

list1 # [1, 2, 'foo', 3]
```